# Pandas: change column values over a certain amount

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following:

```
result.head(4)

    district    end     party   start   state   type    id.thomas   current
564     1      1987     Democrat    1985-01-03  HI  rep     2        1985
565     1      1993     Democrat    1991-01-03  HI  rep     2        1991
566     1      1995     Democrat    1993-01-05  HI  rep     2        2019
567     1      1997     Democrat    1995-01-04  HI  rep     2        2017
```

I would like to change all values greater than 2014 in the column `end` to `2014`. I'm not sure how to go about doing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`clip_upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_upper.html):

```
In [207]:
df['end'] = df['end'].clip_upper(1990)
df

Out[207]:
     district   end     party       start state type  id.thomas  current
564         1  1987  Democrat  1985-01-03    HI  rep          2     1985
565         1  1990  Democrat  1991-01-03    HI  rep          2     1991
566         1  1990  Democrat  1993-01-05    HI  rep          2     2019
567         1  1990  Democrat  1995-01-04    HI  rep          2     2017
```

So in your case `df['end'] = df['end'].clip_upper(2014)` should work

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was wrong with something like `df.loc[df['end'] >= 2014, 'end'] = 2014`?

Comment: @IanS: If it works, then there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @IanS nothing but this method is specific for clamping the values to an upper limit, there is also `clip` and `clip_lower` that do the same thing